# Handling null in JSONObject

Tags: android, json

My app uses Eventbrite API and it crashes when event logo is null.

```
JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(event);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("events");
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
information = jsonObject.getJSONObject("logo");
text = information.getString("url");
name = "eventsImage" + i;
resId = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "id", getPackageName());
new LoadImagefromUrl().execute(new LoadImagefromUrlModel(text, resId));
```

I am trying to make exception for this event, but I am not very experienced with JSONObjects and I don't know how if statement should look like

I have tried the following, but it didn't work

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("logo")!=null
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to catch `JSONException` in

```
information = jsonObject.getJSONObject("logo");
```

like

```
try{
    information = jsonObject.getJSONObject("logo");
}catch(JSONException je){
    //json object not found
}
```

See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject(java.lang.String))

which says - `public JSONObject getJSONObject (String name)`

```
Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject, or throws otherwise.
```

OR, You can use `optJSONObject` like this -

```
if(jsonObject.optJSONObject("logo")!=null)'
```

Because `optJSONObject` doesn't throws exceptions instead returns `null` if no key found

Answer (score 1):

It crashes because you are trying to retrieve an object that does not exist. If object might be `null` you should be using `jsonObject.optJsonObject("logo")` instead.